# How to use PHP Xdebug with requests coming from another device?

Tags: php, xdebug

I have a PC where I run my PHP application. It has Xdebug. I can use it in my IDE when I am working on localhost.

I have a mobile application which is connected to the same wifi network with the PC. Mobile application sends HTTP requests to PHP application on the PC. However, in this case I am unable to debug PHP application on the PC. It doesn't stop at breakpoints.

Same thing happens if I send a request to the PC that PHP application is running on from another PC in the wifi network. Code doesn't stop at breakpoints.

Xdebug has remote_autostart to true. So I don't send and don't need a parameter in the url to debug the application.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the code that will run when the phone send a request. Send the request from the phone. Switch to your IDE it should be sitting on your breakpoint

Comment: 1) *"Xdebug has remote_autostart to true."* What does Xdebug log has to say about it? https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log 2) Is your IDE is in debug mode already (e.g. listening for incoming debug connections)? 3) And just in case -- with Postman or alike you can make your API/ordinary calls right from the same PC.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I already tried that. Somehow if request is not sent from the PC running the application, breakpoints aren't catched.

Answer (score 0):

Config which works for me in such situations:

in /etc/php7/apache2/php.ini

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
xdebug.overload_var_dump = 0
xdebug.remote_mode = req
```

Another problem was that this was somehow overriden by /etc/php7/conf.d/xdebug.ini

Just make sure that you have same values in both configs.